# Отфиксить grub и настроить загрузку варианта двух ОС: Ubuntu и Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, grub, uefi, dual-boot

У меня есть ноутбук DELL с предустановленной ОС Ubuntu 16.04. Кроме того, я решил заменить DVD / RW на новый SSD. Предварительно был установлен Windows 10 на новом SSD с использованием моего другого ПК, поэтому я не вставил SSD в ноутбук для установки Win 10.

В настоящее время у меня есть ноутбук в следующей конструкции:  первый SSD с Ubuntu, который работает правильно, и второй SSD с Win 10, который не загружается как вторая ОС.

Когда я проверяю диски в Ubuntu, я вижу два диска, но я не могу использовать второй SSD, так как он был создан в NTFS.

Я попытался использовать Grub-customizer, но он не нашел Win 10.

Вопрос в том, как я могу отфиксить grub и настроить загрузку варианта двух ОС: Ubuntu и Windows 10?

Comment: Установить os-prober?

Comment: Нет, не видит на втором диске Win. После нажатия F12 винды также нет в выборе, только ubuntu. Хотя на ПК я проверял, у меня показывало 2 ОС Windows в меню. А когда SSD-диск вставил в ноут, то пока не могу сделать так чтобы загрузить Win 10

Comment: Чудеса. Давно ли убунта разучилась работать с NTFS, интересно...

Comment: Использовал строку  sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sdb3. На sdb3 находится Windows. Но выдает ошибку can't find in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Ввел /etc/grub.d/40_custom через терминал, но файл не открывается. Открыл через документы, но не дает права на запись. Хотел указать menuentry "Windows 10" {
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set B4A6AEB7A6AE7A0E
chainloader +1
}   чтобы он подключал мой второй диск при загрузке...